# Рапный или раповый?

Tags: выбор-слов

Лиманы рапные или раповые? Что употребить корректнее?

Answer (score 2):

Правильно: рапные.

[https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/235534/Рапной](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/235534/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9)

Пример:

Донные соляные залежи рапных озер, покрытые сверху рассолами и илами, могут карстоваться восходящими источниками подозерных напорных вод, проложивших себе путь через подстилающие илы соляной залежи. А.И. Дзенс-Литовский, «Соляные озера СССР и их минеральные богатства», 1968 г.

`Раповые` - такого нет в словарях.

Answer (score 2):

*Рапный* или *раповый?* Правильно говорить *рапно́й, рапны́е.*

**Рапа́** (*ж*.) — природный солевой рассол солёных озер, морских заливов с концентрацией, превышающей содержание солей в морской воде нормального состава (из словаря Ефремовой).

[рапно́й](https://classes.ru/all-russian/dictionary-russian-academ-term-67491.htm)
Содержащий в себе рапу. Связанный с применением рапы.

*Принимать **рапные** ванны*; *Едкая рапная вода лимана, наполнявшая башмаки, разъедала натертые ноги мальчика* (В. П. Катаев. Катакомбы).

По А. А. Зализняку: рапно́й, рапна́я, рапно́е, **рапны́е**...